# Can we use Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3.x as a docker registry with Spinnaker?

Tags: nexus, continuous-delivery, spinnaker

We are currently using Dockerhub with Spinnaker for a deployment pipeline. Does spinnaker support Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3.x?

Comment: Hope you had able to get working this spinnaker-nexus integration. I've also same requirement, but it's not working yet. Please see this question I posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59067591/spinnaker-nexus-integration and advise. Also please share the docs or configuration steps you had for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Spinnaker uses the docker registry API to talk to the docker registry, so as long as Nexus Repository Manager supports calling to the same endpoints ( i.e, catalog and tags/list endpoints ) then it should work. The only cases where this is problematic is when there is custom authentication between the registry and spinnaker or when it does not use the traditional paths for the docker registry endpoints.