# Spinnaker Nexus Integration

Tags: nexus, spinnaker, nexus3, spinnaker-halyard

I'm facing issue while integrating spinnaker with Nexus.
Basically, here is my process - Building docker image using Jenkins and uploading to Nexus. Next, want to trigger spinnaker pipelines based on new image available on Nexus to deploy apps on kubernetes.

I've used these 2 commands

```
hal config provider docker-registry enable

hal config provider docker-registry account add my-docker-registry \
    --address <pvtIP>:9082 \
    --repositories repository/<repoName> \
    --username <userName> \
    --password
```

Getting error as below

```
+ Get current deployment
  Success
- Add the my-docker-registry account
  Failure
Problems in default.provider.dockerRegistry.my-docker-registry:
! ERROR Unable to fetch tags from the docker repository:
  repository/test-docker-snapshots/, Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext
  connection?
? Can the provided user access this repository?
- WARNING None of your supplied repositories contain any tags.
  Spinnaker will not be able to deploy any docker images.
? Push some images to your registry.
- Failed to add account my-docker-registry for provider
  dockerRegistry.
```

is it mandatory to have nexus on HTTPS ? I'm running on http, and using in internal network only...

please advise.. thanks..

Answer (score 1):

If your nexus repo is running on HTTP then you should set `--insecure-registry` flag in your command. So you would final command would be as follows:

```
hal config provider docker-registry account add my-docker-registry \
    --address <pvtIP>:9082 \
    --repositories repository/<repoName> \
    --insecure-registry true \
    --username <userName> \
    --password
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, will try this.